# Flash AS3 - Importing external SWF causes Error #2007

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a weird issue with importing external SWF in ActionScript 3.0.
I want to import a SWF made with EasyPano TourWeaver 7.96 but when I'm doing this I'm getting the `Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.` Here is the code:

```
var VRArea:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

VRArea.x = 0;
VRArea.y = 96;

addChild(VRArea);

var my_Loader:Loader = new Loader();
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest("vr/vr_Candela.swf");

my_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
my_Loader.load(urlRequest);

function loaderComplete(event:Event):void {
    VRArea.addChild(my_Loader);
}
```

The complete error is shown below:

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Il valore del parametro type deve essere diverso da null.
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/addEventListener()
at `[::-V/5?()
at ->::4J/Step4_2_startUI()
at ->::4J/`Z()
at [A::&=/1?()
at [A::%c/dispatch()
at !A::%D/load()
at ->::4J/Step3_1_LoadConfig()
at ->::4J/Step3()
at ->::4J/Step2_createContext3D()
at ->::4J/%$()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at  $::TWLoadingWindow/+&()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at 0M::1X/;$()
at 0M::1X/3@()
at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply()
at 0M::>5/&S()
```

Additional info: I'm getting only the loading screen of the external SWF.

Comment: I think that your mentioned code is fine and the problem is in the loaded swf.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `event.target` in your listener to add the loader object. More, since you've assigned the listener to `loaderInfo` property, you need to get the object's `content` that is the object with loaded SWF.

```
function loaderComplete(event:Event):void {
    var li:LoaderInfo=event.target as LoaderInfo;
    if (!li) return; // failed typecast
    VRArea.addChild(li.content); // add content
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your snipped but I am getting the same error, nothing has changed. It always stops at loader screen of the external SWF.

Comment: Hmm. Add a listener for errors, `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` at least, and see if that triggers. Probably there was a loading failure which still generates a complete event, but with a null in `content`.

Comment: Just tried. I used this code:

   my_Loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, giveError);
   
   function giveError(errorEvent:IOErrorEvent):void {
    trace("ioErrorHandler: " + errorEvent);
   }

No error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue: The SWF I tried to embed was made with *Flash 11.x* (at least *Flash CS6*) and mine was *Flash 10.0* (*Flash CS5*). I solved by upgrading to *Flash CS6* and publishing again. Now it's fine.